# JasperReport table element is empty if report uses CSV data adapter

Tags: jasper-reports

Created report based on csv data adapter.

Added to report table element.

Table element uses Dataset (Dataset Run) which was created using main csv data adapter.
Dataset property "Use a JRDatasource expression" is set to $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}
[image]

"Parameter Map" is set to $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}

[image].

Table element in Jrxml:

```
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="1420" y="20" width="250" height="50" uuid="0e621b52-2246-4e00-916c-4d0b91f0b727">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table 2_TH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table 2_CH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table 2_TD"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.autoresize.proportional" value="true"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="SHAREHOLDER_STOCK_CATEGORY_DATASET" uuid="25d6de91-b664-49e2-b950-9ef0491cea72">
                    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="119" uuid="a8bbf8cd-009f-41f2-9993-afb9ce0ad1eb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                    <jr:groupFooter groupName="SHAREHOLDER_STOCK_CATEGORY_GROUP">
                        <jr:cell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="119" height="30" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="af6fa926-20a4-4bbe-8389-3c5fe94182a5"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHAREHOLDER_STOCK_CATEGORY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:cell>
                    </jr:groupFooter>
                    <jr:detailCell height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="119" height="20" uuid="28889612-a9a0-42ca-b6d1-3a62338de5a8"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHAREHOLDER_STOCK_CATEGORY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="131" uuid="092c0c0e-7220-4a04-aff9-e19cb74c1586">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                    <jr:groupFooter groupName="SHAREHOLDER_STOCK_CATEGORY_GROUP">
                        <jr:cell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="131" height="30" uuid="038cd67f-89ca-4917-b109-a69cb052c460"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SHAREHOLDER_STOCK_QUANTITY1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:cell>
                    </jr:groupFooter>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table 2_TD" height="20">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="131" height="20" uuid="45de8f2b-c8f1-4826-9e37-4a48928fae7c"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHAREHOLDER_STOCK_QUANTITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:detail>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[1==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                </jr:detail>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
```

When report runs in JasperReport Studio- table elements displays data perfectly fine
[image]
.

But when I try to print same jrxml using JRXlsxExporter to XLSX this table element is empty.

Any Ideas please how to fix this?

Use JasperStudio 6.18.1
JasperReports dependencies in project:

implementation group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.18.1'
implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-annotation-processors:6.7.0'